# Needing to have sms delayed before sending

Tags: java, android

I know this has been asked multiple times, but I am having problems making it work or figuring out what will work best. I need to have the sms wait 2-3 seconds between each message before sending another message. I have looked at and tried handlers, timers and thread sleep and I am not sure which one would be the best use in my situation, or how to make it work right. I am still new to programming, so please take it easy on me.

```
// ---sends an SMS message---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {

    int i;
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    int amount = 10; // just making 10 the default if the EditText has an
                        // invalid value
    try {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(smsamount.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException smsamount) {
    }

    if (amount < 501) {
        for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the blob of code? If it is more than is needed to answer your question, _trim it down!_ Also, is the sms being sent a user-initiated action and you need to impose a rate-limit, or is it something else?

Comment: @cdeszaq sorry about that, I trimmed it down so it just shows the sending sms portion of the code. The user will enter an amount of sms they would like to send themselves for testing purposes. The default is 10 but they can enter up to 500 if the want to. The problem I am running into is that if they enter a high number, the phone tries to send them all at once and causes problems. If I can get them spaced out to a sec or two apart, it will help solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this. I've not tested it, but the idea of using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) should be what you're after.

```
public class SMS extends Activity {
    private final static OnClickListener EMPTY_ON_CLICK_LISTENER = new EmptyOnClickListener();
    TextView smsamount;

    // ---sends an SMS message---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        // just making 10 the default if the EditText has an invalid value
        int amount = 10;

        try {
            amount = Integer.parseInt(smsamount.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException smsamount) {
            // Ignore
        }

        sendSMS(phoneNumber, message, amount);
    }

    // ---sends an SMS message---
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, int count) {
        if (count >= 501) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(SMS.this).setTitle("Maximum amount of messages exceeded!")
                    .setMessage("Please enter 500 or less for the amount of messages")
                    .setNeutralButton("Ok", EMPTY_ON_CLICK_LISTENER).show();
            // Quit early when we know we can't go any further.
            return;
        }

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
        // ---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new SmsSentBroadcastReceiver(getBaseContext()), new IntentFilter(SENT));

        int delaySeconds = 3;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = new SmsScheduler().sendSmsMessages(phoneNumber, message, sentPI, delaySeconds,
                count);

        // You may cancel the scheduled messages with the scheduler.
        // scheduler.shutdownNow();

        new AlertDialog.Builder(SMS.this).setTitle("Attention!")
                .setMessage("Your messages will start sending shortly, please do not press the send sms button again")
                .setNeutralButton("Ok", EMPTY_ON_CLICK_LISTENER).show();
    }

    private static class SmsSentBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context context;

        public SmsSentBroadcastReceiver(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class EmptyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Does nothing
        }
    }

    private static class SmsScheduler {
        public ScheduledExecutorService sendSmsMessages(final String phoneNumber, final String message,
                final PendingIntent sentIntent, int count, int delaySeconds) {
            final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

            final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

            // Create the task that will send a SMS message
            final Runnable sender = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
                }
            };

            // Schedule the messages to be sent at intervals of delaySeconds.
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                scheduler.schedule(sender, delaySeconds * i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }

            return scheduler;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use 2 seconds delay between each sms, use a ScheduledExecutorService thread pool (1 thread is probably enough cause you don't send parallel) and call schedule method with the code to send the sms.
For each call, raise the delay parameter by 2 seconds (0,2,4,6,...)

Hope it helps.